# Connect to GCloud SQL 2 from Node JS App Engine server.js file (standard env)

Tags: node.js, sockets, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, gcloud

I've built a Node.JS project (deployed at www.mischief.app) in App Engine that allows users to submit their name and email to receive product updates.

The Node / Express / Angular side of my project works perfectly, and passes the user submission as an object to server.js. But when my server.js file tries to connect to Google Cloud SQL for MySQL to write the object into a MySQL users table, I get a connection error:

'Error: connect ENOENT /cloudsql/mischief-cloud:us-west2:mischief-db. ...'

I've followed all the documentation as best I could (docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/using-cloud-sql) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/quickstart)), and I don't know what to do next.

How do I connect MySQL to Node on App Engine?

What am I doing wrong?

Here's a link to a screenshot of my server.js file: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTrCr.jpg

Happy to provide more info if that helps!

Comment: Have you tried setting the `config.socketPath` explicitly? e.g. `socketPath: '/cloudsql/<instance details>'` Regardless, I feel like the issue is a malformed socket connection? Can you post full error output?

Comment: Did you get it to work? I am getting Connection refused if i use socketPath

Comment: @RiteshKarwa yes, the answer below was correct. I needed to add '/cloudsql/' in my socketPath variable. If you're still facing an issue, I would recommend you create a new question, since you might be facing a different problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your server.js class, in line 39 you are missing /cloudsql/ , it should look something like:

socketPath: ‘/cloudsql/YOUR-INSTANCE-CONN-NAME‘

You can review the correct config [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/cloudsql/server.js), line 40 which is part of the official Cloud SQL - NodeJs [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/using-cloud-sql) that you mentioned.